# Замена слова "цена" на слово "ценник". Зачем?

Tags: выбор-слов

Почему и зачем вместо слова "цена" употребляют слово "ценник"? В последнее время очень часто это слышу. Если идет разговор о чем-то дорогом или дешевом, если кто-то интересуется ценой какой-либо вещи, то слово "цена" или "стоимость" почти не употребляют, но употребляют слово "ценник". Например, выражения - "дешевый ценник", "высокий ценник", "конский ценник", "ты ценник видел?!", "приемлемый ценник", "ценники одинаковы", "вкусный ценник", "ценник вырос" и т.д.
Почему? Ценник - это бумажка, на которой указана цена, как он может быть конским или приемлемым?

Comment: Вряд ли можно ответить на такой вопрос. Вопрос "почему говорят так-то, а не эдак-то" в рамках лингвистики, как правило, не разрешим. А психология здесь, по идее, офтоп. :)

Answer (score 1):

ЦЕННИК,  Справочник цен на товары или указатель цены. Ц. товаров. ЦЕНА,  1. Денежное выражение стоимости товара или услуг; плата.

Употребление слова ***ценник*** вместо ***цены*** — это обычный молодежный сленг, причем довольно "скромный" его вариант.

Слово образовано способом **переноса значения** по смежности с одной реалии на другую (такой вариант тропа называется метонимией).

Например: *Этому хламу **ценник** — одна европка! Купил тачку, 25 убитых енотов отдал* (у.е.)

Молодежный сленг  **обусловлен желанием говорящего** выделиться из общей среды и  внести эмоциональное разнообразие в свою речь.

Comment: Все так, но есть сомнения в "молодежности" этого сленга. По моим ощущениям, так говорят/пишут и  люди из категории сильно за тридцать, если не за сорок. То есть, либо это было молодежным сленгом лет 15-20 назад, и его носители повзрослели, либо (если действительно нынешние двадцатилетние так говорят) - эээ, затрудняюсь даже сказать, кто от кого это подхватил.. Но согласен с тем, что *ценник* (наряду с *походу*) практически утвердился в языке, к сожалению.